# javascript iterate through array and perform operation based on conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have following array in my localstorage

```
[  
   {  
      "customerId":"30",
      "CustomerContactId":63873
   },
   {  
      "customerId":"26506",
      "CustomerContactId":63874
   },
   {  
      "customerId":"26596",
      "CustomerContactId":63875
   },
   {  
      "customerId":"26597",
      "CustomerContactId":63876
   }
]
```

We have functionality of select customer from dropdown. On select customer, I pass customerId to the function. In function, i call api to generate CustomerContactId for that customerId.
i want to iterate through this array and and want to check if customerId is exist in array then do not execute generate CustomerContactId API but if customerId is not exist in whole array, then create CustomerContactId for that customerId. 
I tried javascript map function. Here this.state.customerContactMap = localstorage array. cust_id = selected customer.

```
this.state.customerContactMap.map(item => {
   if(item.customerId === cust_id) {
     //Do not generate new CustomerContactId
   } else {
     //Generate CustomerContactId API Call
     //it should only generate CustomerContactId if cust_id is not 
     //exist in array
   }
})
```

but i am facing problem that it creates CustomerContactId everytime when it goes to else condition. I need help in conditional logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Array.filter to check if customer Id exists or not.

```js
var data = [{
"customerId": "30",
"CustomerContactId": 63873
}, {
"customerId": "26506",
"CustomerContactId": 63874
}, {
"customerId": "26596",
"CustomerContactId": 63875
}, {
"customerId": "26597",
"CustomerContactId": 63876
}]

function getCustomer(id){
  return data.filter(function(e){
    if(e.customerId == id){
      return true;
    }
  });
}

var custId = getCustomer("26597");

if(custId.length == 0){
  console.log("Not exists");
  //network call
}else{
  console.log("Exists");
  console.log(custId);
  //normal operations of cust id available
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#some` to check if `customerId` is present in your array.

```js
const customerContactMap = [{ "customerId": "30", "CustomerContactId": 63873 }, { "customerId": "26506", "CustomerContactId": 63874 }, { "customerId": "26596", "CustomerContactId": 63875 }, { "customerId": "26597", "CustomerContactId": 63876 }],
      custId = 30;
if(customerContactMap.some(({customerId}) => customerId == custId)){
  console.log('found');
} else {
  //Execute API
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only having this condition:

```
 if(item.customerId === cust_id) {
```

Seems like type of `item.customerId` and `cust_id` are not same type.

Try conversion:

```
 if(item.customerId == cust_id) {
```

OR

```
 if(item.customerId === cust_id.toString()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.some()` instead of `.map()`.

As per [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

For example:

```
if(arr.some(({ customerId }) => customerId === selectedId))
  console.log("Selected Found");
else
  console.log("Selected Not Found");
```

**Demo:**

```js
let arr = [{ "customerId": "30", "CustomerContactId": 63873}, {"customerId": "26506","CustomerContactId": 63874}, {"customerId": "26596","CustomerContactId": 63875}, {"customerId": "26597","CustomerContactId": 63876}];

let selectedId = "26596";

if(arr.some(({ customerId }) => customerId === selectedId))
  console.log("Selected Found");
else
  console.log("Selected Not Found");
```